# bootstrap 3 navbar does wrap on 768px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Thats my pen: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/VLvRqX

When I resize my browser window to under 768px width, then the content of the navbar wraps to a vertical menu.

Why is that?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li class="history-link">
                        <a href="http://www.test.com/de/deu/produkte/k%C3%BChlen-gefrieren/page.html">ThatsMe</a>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>



<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">French <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/Culture/SetCulture?cultureName=en-GB">Englisch</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Culture/SetCulture?cultureName=de-AT">#de-AT</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Culture/SetCulture?cultureName=bg-BG">#bg-BG</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

                </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's how they have implemented it - Responsive Design View. If you don't want that to happen, you have to override the styles. They have used media query to detect the width.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {}
```

They are changing

```
.nav > li {
    float:left;
}
```

to

```
.nav > li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Yes I checked the bootstrap 3 source css file for 768px media but I can not find the right now so I know which style changed...

Comment: Check my updated answer. You can override those by adding your own class.

Comment: I am looking into the source code of the bootstrap.css file and I can not see your changes there??? Can you tell me your version + line number where the code should be, please?

Comment: ok got it. I always set float:left for a certain menu id to prevent the wrap :-)